# How to pass data from one View function to another for a multi-step form?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm currently working a developing a Hockey League management website. The feature I am currently working on, is entering a "Game Report". This is where a score keeper enters in all the details for that game once it has been completed. The Game report feature itself requires 3 steps to be completed.

1. Selecting the game for which you want to enter the report for.
2. A form which populates the roster of both teams, with a checkbox for each player to mark off if they played in the game. In addition, there is 2 separate formsets to add players for either team if they aren't already on the roster.
3. The final part of the game report, where you enter in the goals, penalties, and the game results. Where the goals and penalties are formsets, and the game results are a simple model form.

The confusion comes from the fact that data from the prior step, is required for the current step.

SelectGame View (Step 1) - No issues here

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def selectGame(request):
    games = Game.objects.all().values(
        'iceSlot__date',
        'homeTeam__name',
        'awayTeam__name',
        'id'
    )
    context = {'games': games}
    return render(request, "home/select-game.html", context)
```

Transition From Step 1 to Step 2 occurs in select-game.html (Also No issue)

```
<a href="{% url 'gameReportRoster' game.id %}" class="btn btn-fill btn-primary btm-sm">Select</a>
```

gameReportRoster View (Step 2) - Issue located here trying to get the data that comes from this view, over to step 2

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def gameReportRoster(request, pk):
    # Need to add in to the Game Form, the season for the game
    game = Game.objects.get(id=pk)
    homeTeam = Team.objects.get(id=game.homeTeam_id)
    awayTeam = Team.objects.get(id=game.awayTeam_id)
    homeTeamPlayers = Player.objects.filter(team__id=homeTeam.id).all().values().order_by('lastName')
    awayTeamPlayers = Player.objects.filter(team__id=awayTeam.id).all().values().order_by('lastName')
    currentSeason = Season.objects.get(currentSeason=True)
    formsetHomeTeam = PlayerFormSet(queryset=Player.objects.none(), prefix='home')
    formsetAwayTeam = PlayerFormSet(queryset=Player.objects.none(), prefix='away')

    games = Game.objects.all().values(
        'iceSlot__date',
        'homeTeam__name',
        'awayTeam__name',
        'id'
    )
    context = {
        'games': games,
        'homeTeam': homeTeam,
        'awayTeam': awayTeam,
        'homeTeamPlayers': homeTeamPlayers,
        'awayTeamPlayers': awayTeamPlayers,
        'formsetHomeTeam': formsetHomeTeam,
        'formsetAwayTeam': formsetAwayTeam,
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        OMMITED BUSINESS LOGIC HERE

        allPlayersWhoPlayed = Player.objects.filter(id__in=allPlayedList)

        teams = Team.objects.filter(id__in=teamList)
        gameResultForm = GameResultForm(teams=teams)

        formsetGoal = GoalFormSet(form_kwargs={'players': allPlayersWhoPlayed}, prefix='goal')
        formsetPenalty = PenaltyFormSet(form_kwargs={'players': allPlayersWhoPlayed}, prefix='penalty')

        context = {
            'formsetGoal': formsetGoal,
            'formsetPenalty': formsetPenalty,
            'gameResultForm': gameResultForm
        }
        # return gameReportStats(request, context)
        return render(request, "home/game-report-stats.html", context)

    return render(request, "home/game-report-roster.html", context)
```

This is where I am totally stuck, I need to get that new Context dict I created from that view, over into this one, which properly renders everything

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def gameReportStats(request, context):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Test')
    return render(request, "home/game-report-stats.html", context)
```

Comment: I don't understand the commented out `return gameReportStats(request, context)` just uncomment it and remove `return render(request, "home/game-report-stats.html", context)`

Comment: @Ahtisham if I remove both of those, how am I going to get to my template and view for the stats? home/game-report-stats.html

Comment: I didn"t said remove both just the render part

Comment: @Ahtisham Oh I see what you mean now, so the reason that is currently commented out, because when I use that, the URL still says the same, and still shows game-report-roster/PK. In addition, when I use that, it automatically does a post request in gameReportStats

Comment: I don't understand your question correct me if i am wrong you just want to send the dictionary that you create in `gameReportRoster` post request to `gameReportStats` so that context can be passed to `home/game-report-stats.html` html where the context will be shown ?

Comment: Why you don't rename context to `context1` and `context2`? and `return render(request, "home/game-report-stats.html", context=context2)`

Comment: @Ahtisham So the issue with what you suggested is, that is really confuses the post requests. Your suggestion works that it does take me to stage 3 of my form, the problem is, hitting submit on that stage 3, triggers a Post Request in the views for both Part 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Django can only send data from one view to another through the database. So if you want to make a form in several steps, you need to make a temp model that will keep data of first form available for second form.

In order to keep you DB clean, add a timestamp of creation into your temp model, and clean-up this temp model from time to time based on the timestamp.

This is a litte bit nasty, but this is the straightest solution.

You could use a 'Context' model with 2 fields : JSONField and ForeignKey for the user. That will allow you to serialize/deserialize you python native dictionary into the library and make the link with the user and so the previous form.

The other solution would be to keep this information on the client side. But this would require to transform fully your solution to something totally different as, for example, Django Rest (API) + React or Vue or js.